# Constructing adjacency matrix based on a given range of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, code-review, code-request

Given

```
SeedRandom[3];
n = 5;
mat = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {n, n}];
adjMat[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := 
    Partition[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] & /@ Flatten[matrix], Length[matrix]]
```

I generate an adjacency matrix based on `lB = -2` and `uB = 1`:

```
adjMat[mat, -2, 1]

(*output*)
{{1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

This output is what I aimed to find. However, I am not particularly happy with the `adjMat[...]` function as it first converts `mat` to a list and then reconstructs the desired adjacency matrix using `Partition`.

Can we make this `adjMat[...]` function work with matrix input (without flattening) rather than a list? Any improvement is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[adjMat2]

adjMat2[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := Map[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] &, matrix, {-1}]

adjMat2[mat, -2, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[adjMat3]
adjMat3[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := UnitStep[matrix - lB] UnitStep[uB - matrix]

adjMat3[mat, -2, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

And, for fun,

```
PrecedesTilde = Boole @* Map[Thread] @* Thread @* LessEqual;

-2 ≾ mat ≾ 1
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
MatrixForm @ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With vectorized ops

```
Clip[
  mat, 
  {-2, 1},
  {0, 0}
  ] // Unitize

{
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
  {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, 
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
 }
```

or as a function

```
adjMat[mat_, lb_, ub_] :=
 Clip[
   mat, 
   {lb, ub},
   {0, 0}
   ] // Unitize
```

Comment: in your `code`, is there any particular reason why `mat*adjMat[mat,lB,uB]` returns the adjacency matrix itself? The `code` by @kglr returns the matrix with the elements selected by the adjacency matrix, though in my question, I did not indicate this multiplication.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I'm willing to be you're using it wrong. If you're doing `mat * Clip[mat, {-2, 1}, {0, 0}] // Unitize`, that will give you something different than `mat*adjMat[mat, -2, 1]`. The latter works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `UnitBox[]` for this:

```
adjMat[mat_, lb_, ub_] := UnitBox[(2 mat - (lb + ub))/(2 (ub - lb))]
```

Using OP's example:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[3];
            With[{n = 5}, mat = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {n, n}]];
            adjMat[mat, -2, 1]]
   {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

---

In a lot of cases, one might want a `SparseArray[]` instead; here's how to get one:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[3];
            With[{n = 5}, mat = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {n, n}]];
            SparseArray[Position[mat, _?(Between[{-2, 1}]), {2}] -> 1, 
                        Dimensions[mat]]]
```